# Hamburger not functional

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am unable to get a response when clicking on the hamburger icon. I'm new and can't seem to find what I am missing.

```
  <a href="nts.html" class="pull-left brand-font"><img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4225/34641075042_5dec5a63a4_z.jpg"><p id="motto">"Your needs.....our goal"</p></a>

  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
  <li><a href="nts.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="ftp://66.76.63.143">FTP</a></li>
  <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>      
   <li><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you load bootstrap js file ?

Comment: I did. I have the js and css linked.

Comment: Where?  It needs to be at the bottom of the document and you also need jQuery loaded before the bootstrap js file.

Comment: I did notice I was missing the jQuery though and it made it functional. Thanks!